# How do I access my newly added fields in a spatialite layer from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatialite

Forgive my language, I am a newbie in QGIS. I created a spatialite layer and added 4 fields. As I was working on the project I realised that I didn't need one of the fields, and I needed to add 3 different fields, to make them 6 in total.I encountered the limitation of SQLite not being able to delete created fields. So I looked for a [GUI](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) option of modifying the database. I successfully deleted that one column and added 3 new ones. Now the problem is when I open the layer in QGIS to edit the feature attributes, only the old 4 columns are still available. My spatial layer initially had these attributes:
[image: These were my initial fields].
After updating the SQLite database using [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), below is the structure of my table from DB Browser for SQLite:
[image: modified table for the layer]
Coming back to QGIS to add more information to newly created fields, I still find the old 4 fields:
[image: Old attribute fields displayed after table structure updated].

Anyone to help so that my layer loads all fields for feature attributes please?

Comment: Did you try adding the layer to QGIS again?